# Problem with NIntegrate and more general problems with NDSolve

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, numerical-integration

I'm new to Mathematica and I'm receiving little help for a (to me) quite difficult problem I'm trying to solve. I want to solve logarithmic Boltzmann equation for abundance of dark matter.
I'm having different problems:

1. I obtain the error "The integrand has evaluated to non-numerical values..." even though I've tried to use NumericQ as read in this forum
2. "Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at x=0.01" (which I think may be due to the presence of neq as a non evaluated function)

I noted neq isn't evaluated because of the fact I'm defining it with x as a numerical variable, but I need to pass it to NDSolve and I don't know how to do that with this.

```
Needs["DifferentialEquations`NDSolveUtilities`"];
Mx = 100;
gx = 2;
gs = 106.75;
g = 100;
Mp = 10^19;
\[Sigma]v = 10^-10;

Clear[neq, f];
neq[x_?NumericQ, m_] := 
  NIntegrate[(gx/(2 Pi Pi)) Exp[-x Sqrt[1 + p p/(m m)]] p p, {p, 0, 
    Infinity}, MaxRecursion -> 50];
stot[x_] := (2 Pi Pi/45) gs Mx^3 /(x^3);
Yeq[x_, m_] := neq[x, m]/stot[x];
Weq[x_, m_] := Log[Yeq[x, m]];
xmin = 10^-2; xmax = 10^2;
xdom = {x, xmin, xmax};
ODE = {W'[
     x] == (0.264 Mp Mx gs \[Sigma]v/(Sqrt[g])) (Exp[
         2 Weq[x, m] - W[x]] - Exp[W[x]])/(x^2)};
Y0 = 0;
W0 = -10^10; (*ideally I'd have W0 = -Infinity and Y0 = 0 being W0 = \
log(Y0)*)
BC = {W[xmin] == W0};
Wsol = NDSolve[{ODE, BC}, W[x], xdom, Method -> "StiffnessSwitching"]

Plot[Evaluate[W[x] /. Wsol], {x, 10^-2, 10^2}, PlotRange -> Automatic]
```

Thanks for your time!

Edit. I'm adding the expected behaviour of the solution from x = 1 to x = xmax
[image: Solution]

Comment: The first error is due to a wrong definition of `neq`: the variable `m` needs to be numerical too, so the definition should be `neq[x_?NumericQ, m_?NumericQ] :=...`. This however does not solve the all the problems, because another error appears with `NDSolve` complaining that there are more variable than equations.

Comment: Also inside the exponential, in `Weq` there is an undefined `m`: which constant should it be? Giving a random value to `m` the program works. In the above comment I forgot to say that in the definition of all of your functions you should add `?NumericQ` for all the variables not just in `neq`.

Comment: One more thing: `Mp` and `\[Sigma]v` differ by 29 orders of magnitude, this is likely to give numerical problems.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for your observations. I just corrected that little m in Weq(x,m), thanks! I changed my variables to numerical ones as you say, but still it doesn't plot a thing.. does it work to you in that way?

Comment: Mp and Sigmav are so, the first one is Planck mass and the second one in a specific value of cross section I can't modify. The stiffness of the equation is part of the problem I'm trying to overcome

Comment: Sorry I just noticed this: you define `W0=-10^10` and you exponentiate it, this will give overflow and underflow problems. Renormalize you parameters. You can always set the Planck constant to 1 and rescale consequently other variables. With a small value for `W0` `NDSolve` gives a solution.

Comment: Problem is I'm already in natural units using GeV and that's Planck Mass, therefore there's no way to reduce the gap between the numbers without changing also the solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**FINAL ANSWER**

Here is the improved code. I have changed the method of `NDSolveValue` to `Method -> {"StiffnessSwitching",  Method -> {"ExplicitRungeKutta", Automatic}}` and increased the `AccuracyGoal`. Better results require higher accuracy, but **will be much more time consuming** (The code below required about a minute on my computer). So here is the code and the plot.

```
Needs["DifferentialEquations`NDSolveUtilities`"];
Mx = 100;
gx = 2;
gs = 106.75;
g = 100;
Mp = 10^19;
\[Sigma]v = 10^-10;

Clear[neq];
neq[x_?NumericQ, m_?NumericQ] := 
  NIntegrate[(gx/(2 Pi Pi)) Exp[-x Sqrt[1 + p p/(m m)]] p p, {p, 0, 
    Infinity}];
stot[x_?NumericQ] := (2 Pi Pi/45) gs Mx^3/(x^3);
Yeq[x_?NumericQ, m_?NumericQ] := neq[x, m]/stot[x];
xmin = 10^-1; xmax = 10^2;
xdom = {x, xmin, xmax};
ODE = {Y'[
     x] == (0.264 Mp Mx gs \[Sigma]v/(Sqrt[g])) (Yeq[x, Mx]^2 - 
        Y[x]^2)/(x^2)};
BC = {Y[xmin] == 10^-6};
Wsol = NDSolveValue[{ODE, BC}, Y, xdom, 
  Method -> {"StiffnessSwitching", 
    Method -> {"ExplicitRungeKutta", Automatic}}, AccuracyGoal -> 20]
LogLogPlot[Wsol[x], {x, 0.1, 100}, PlotRange -> All]
```

Plot:

[image]

**OLD ANSWER**

Ok here is a possible solution. Since `W0` is too high, you could write the ODE in terms of `Y[x]=Exp[W[x]]` setting a small number for the initial condition. For example you could do something like this:

```
Needs["DifferentialEquations`NDSolveUtilities`"];
Mx = 100;
gx = 2;
gs = 106.75;
g = 100;
Mp = 10^19;
\[Sigma]v = 10^-10;

Clear[neq, f];
neq[x_?NumericQ, m_?NumericQ] := 
  NIntegrate[(gx/(2 Pi Pi)) Exp[-x Sqrt[1 + p p/(m m)]] p p, {p, 0, 
    Infinity}, MaxRecursion -> 50];
stot[x_?NumericQ] := (2 Pi Pi/45) gs Mx^3/(x^3);
Yeq[x_?NumericQ, m_?NumericQ] := neq[x, m]/stot[x];
xmin = 10^-2; xmax = 10^2;
xdom = {x, xmin, xmax};
ODE = {Y'[x] == 
    Y[x] (0.264 Mp Mx gs \[Sigma]v/(Sqrt[g])) (Yeq[x, Mx]/Y[x] - 
        Y[x])/(x^2)};   
BC = {Y[xmin] == 0.1};
Wsol = NDSolveValue[{ODE, BC}, Y[x], xdom, Method -> "StiffnessSwitching"]

Plot[Wsol,xdom]
```

The plot is ugly:

[image]

But notice that in the `NDSolveValue` code I set `m=Mx` just to put in a value, since you did not provide the correct constant, so the result may vary. Also I set `Y[xmin]` to 0.1, probably you should play a bit with this boundary.

Comment: Hello! First of all, thank you so much for helping me with this problem, it means a lot.
Now m = Mx is correct as you guessed, but the boundary condition needs to be given for Y(xmin) = 0 or at least very close to it. I was working with W(x) = log(Y(x)) to make the integration more efficient since Y spans over more than 40 orders of magnitudes. 
Using the BC I told you I obtain something nosense given that the expected behaviour of Y(x) should be decreasing. I understand this is a particularly hard problem to deal with. I'm adding the (expected) plot we should obtain from x = 1 to x = xmax

Comment: @Fredrigo6 See my update. I will try later to see if can do better

Comment: Hello! Thanks a lot for your help. I'm going to bed now so I'll talk to you tomorrow!

Comment: @Fredrigo6. See the update. Probably rescaling the parameters would require smaller accuracy, but if you can't change them this is a solution.

Comment: This kinda works! I guess it's just a difficult problem. Imagine trying to solve it from x = 0.001 and with boundary condition Y[xi] = 0. thanks for you help though! I'll accept the answer, but if you are intrigued by it I'll continue working on it so in case let's continue the conversation!

(How can I accept your answer?)

Comment: @Fredrigo6 there is a green button below the votes of the answer

Comment: There's no button. I only can see the arrow to up or down vote, then the bookmark and the activity button..

Comment: @Fredrigo6 The bookmark and activity button are below the question votes. The checkmark is below the answer votes.